# How to add different css style in a jsp list

Tags: java, css, hibernate, jsp, foreach

Hi guys i need help about a list inside a jsp (first screen).

[image: now]

I would to format the list like this:

[image: after]

How can i differentiate the list elements? Is better a back-end approach or a front-end approach? Thx.

JAVA

```
            List<Menu> listMenu = meRepo.listMenu();
            for (Menu menu : listMenu) {
                MenuView mView = menuView.new MenuView();
                mView.setIdMenu(menu.getIdMenu());
                mView.setName(menu.getName());
                mView.setAction(menu.getAction());
                enableView.getListMenu().add(mView);
            }


            req.setAttribute(RequestAttributeKeys.VIEW_KEY, enableView);
            dispatchForward("listEnableMenu.tiles");
```

JSP

```
<table class="table table-header-rotated">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <!-- First column header is not rotated -->
   <th></th>
  <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
  <c:forEach var="listRole" items="${requestScope.view.listRole}"    varStatus="counter">
        <th class="rotate"><div><span><c:out value="${listRole.nameRole}">      </c:out></span></div></th>
  </c:forEach>
</tr> 
  </thead>
     <tbody>
   <c:forEach var="listMenu" items="${requestScope.view.listMenu}" varStatus="counter">
        <tr>
              <th class="row-header"><c:out value="${listMenu.name}"></c:out></th>
              <c:forEach var="listRole" items="${requestScope.view.listRole}" varStatus="counter">
                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>
              </c:forEach>
        </tr>
   </c:forEach>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Please can you show your rendered html

Comment: there are two screen :)

Comment: Html not screen shot

Comment: hi pete the code is in the topic :

Comment: afgter the screen there are codes java and jsp(html)

Comment: The code in the question is before it has been rendered, I need to see the code after it has been rendered - without any of the jsp in it - just flat html.  If you are not willing to read the help centre to see how to ask a proper question or follow simple queries for more code, then good luck to you.  This question in it's current form will only get answers like the one below

Comment: ok i will post the render

Answer (score 0):

Add a new conditional class to check if the  is not the first index. Something like:

```
< th class="row-header ${!counter.first ? 'indent-class' : ''}">
```

Should do just fine.

Comment: Ah I see. My advice would be to add an new property to the listMenuItems in the backend as a flag to show how they should be indented, or manipulate the page styling with more CSS and JS.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code after render:

```
<table class="table table-header-rotated">
 <thead>
   <tr>
  <!-- First column header is not rotated -->
    <th></th>
  <!-- Following headers are rotated -->

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Super user</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Gestore</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Fatca Office</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Responsabile antiriciclaggio</span>  </div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>22</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Operatore</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Diagnostico DPS</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Responsabile intermediario</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>EDP</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Group AML</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>AML Officer</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Agenzia delle Entrate</span></div></th>

        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Disattivato</span></div></th>

</tr> 
 </thead>
   <tbody>

        <tr>

              <th class="row-header">MANAGEMENT PARAMETERS</th>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

              <th class="row-header">SYSTEM PARAMETERS</th>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

              <th class="row-header">Gestione Gruppi Intermediari</th>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

              <th class="row-header">Gestione Intermediari</th>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

              <th class="row-header">Gestione Ruoli</th>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

              <th class="row-header">Gestione Utenti</th>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

              <th class="row-header">Gestione Menu</th>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

              <th class="row-header">Gestione Politiche Password</th>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

              <th class="row-header">Gestione Application Suites</th>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

                <td><input name="column3[]" type="checkbox" value="row1-column3"></td>

        </tr>
```